# Bounding trace operator from below

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

In a paper, I've read the following thing. Here $\Omega$ is a smooth domain

> From the standard trace theorem we know there exists a bounded linear operator $$\gamma: H^1(\Omega) \rightarrow H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)$$ such that $\gamma_0 u=u_{|\partial W}$ for $u$ smooth and that satisfies
> $$\|\gamma_0 u\|_{H^{\frac{1}{2}}} \geq C \|u\|_{H^1} \qquad \forall u\in H^1(\Omega) \setminus \ker(\gamma_0)$$

I don't know how to show the last equality.

If I can prove that $\gamma_0$ has closed range, then I have that it's bounded from below ( by a standard result coming from Open Mapping Theorem). However, I don't know how to prove it. Any hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: I have doubts. Take a $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and consider the sequence $u_\epsilon=u+\epsilon$

Comment: Piero's example is convincing, of course, but the inequality also doesn't make sense on general grounds, because we can always make the RHS large by giving $u$ extra oscillations in the interior of our domain.

Comment: You may want to  assume $u\in (\ker \gamma_0)^\perp$.   In this case the inequality follows from the open mapping theorem since $\gamma_0: (\ker \gamma_0)^\perp\to H^{1/2}$ is onto.  Here $\perp$ refers to the orthogonal complement in the Hilbert space $H^1(\Omega)$

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thanks, I need a last clarification. How do you use the open mapping to show that bound? I really cannot see how

Comment: I mean, to have a bound from below, I need $\gamma_0$ to be injective and to have a closed range, and I don't see why in this case the range of $\gamma_0$ is closed @LiviuNicolaescu

Comment: The map from $(\ker \gamma_0)^\perp\to H^{1/2}$ is bijective and continuous

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thanks so much, now I see the implications. The fact that $(\ker \gamma_0)^\perp\to H^{1/2}$ is bijective and continuous implies that the inverse is bounded, which is equivalent to say that it's bounded from below.

Comment: Btw, in my case $\ker(\gamma_0)=H_0^1(\Omega)$, so I think that writing $u\in H^1(\Omega) \setminus \ker(\gamma_0)$ as I did makes sense: I am indeed excluding all the trace-zero functions and my $\gamma_0$ is still injective and surjective. Why do I need to write $(\ker \gamma_0)^\perp$? @LiviuNicolaescu

Comment: Just think in terms of finite dimensional inner product spaces. Given a space $V$ and a subspace $W$, there is a huge difference between $V\setminus W$ and $W^\perp$. The former, for example, is usually not a vector space.

Comment: Though, perchance you made a typo and meant the quotient $H^1(\Omega) / \mathrm{ker}(\gamma_0)$ and not the set difference?